# Android, bring already started activity back to front

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-intent

My android application has multiple activities. Each activity has a 'Back to Home' button. For example, Main activity opens sub-activity A, sub-activity A opens sub-activity B.

On the screen of sub-activity B, there's a 'Back to Home' button which is supposed to bring back the Main activity into visibility.

I've tried the flag **Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT** but no use.

This is a part of my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
...
<activity android:name="vn.agritrade.Main_Activity"
android:label="Agritrade"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
android:launchMode="singleInstance">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
...
```

This is how I relaunch the Main activity:

```
/**
 * Relaunch main activity (called by 'Back to Home' button)
 */
public void open_main_activity(View view) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(this,Main_Activity.class);
  intent.putExtra(DEFAULT_EXTRA,"");
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
  startActivity(intent);    
}
```

What else should I need?

Comment: since you are recreating the main activity (i suppose you are not saving the state of the main activity)  on home pressed, why do you need flags ? if you want the intermediate activities closed, you should explicitly finish them while navigating away from them

Comment: yeah, i finish all the sub-activities, this is my final solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final solution is:

- Keep the main activity stay open
- Each time I need to turn back to main screen: close all sub-activities

Answer (score 2):

Use below code it may help,

```
    Intent intentHome = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    intentHome.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intentHome.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intentHome.putExtra(DEFAULT_EXTRA,"");
    startActivity(intentHome);
```

It is worked for me.

Don't forget to mark as answer it is help to you.

Answer (score 1):

`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` may solve your problem

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,Main_Activity.class);
intent.putExtra(DEFAULT_EXTRA,"");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: the same like FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT, it doesn't work :(

Comment: Will back to the front from history stack.that flag just brings it to the front if it's still there. You cant retroactively ensure that the OS didn't kill it to regain resources